# Spamfilter using regex with matches method for string

Tags: java, regex, spam-prevention

For a school assignment we are asked to make a simple spam filter using regex and the matches() method for strings. The 2 are words are spam and viagra. It should work even if its spelled with lower case or upper case, repeated letters or blankspaces between characters. For example "”V i AA gggg RrR aA" or "xxxSPAMyyy”.

This is what i have right now

```
     if(Item.getSubject().matches("(?i).*s.*p.*a.*m.*") ||Item.getMessage().matches("(?i).*v.*i.*a.*g.*r.*a.*")){
        return false;
    }
```

and it works for the examples shown above but also for strings i dont want it to work for. Like sentences with just the right characters in order. Anyone who knows a good solution?

Comment: More, `"(?i).*s.*p.*a.*m.*"` matches `Superpharm`. You cannot just replace `.*` between letters with `[a-zA-Z]*`

Comment: Hint: What does the `.*` between letters do?

Comment: see [this](https://regex101.com/r/ryegAZ/2) for what @JoeC is trying to say.

Comment: Spam filters will never be 100% correct without some sort of artificial intelligence behind it. The closest I think you'll be able to get is using something like `[v\W]+[i\W]+[a\W]+[g\W]+[r\W]+[a\W]+`, but then again, this could have unforeseen matches like `Get to their house via Grand Street`

Comment: `The spa may be closed now!`

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-process or normalize your input data to make matching with regular expressions more simple. For example, if you remove all space characters from the input, you regular expression will get much more simple and reliable. After normalization of "Buy V i AA gggg RrR aA!!!" will become "BuyViAAggggRrRaA!!!" and can be easily matched with the "(?i).*v+i+a+g+r+a+.*" expression. Of course, keep in mind that you will never get it 100% correct with regular expressions.